# Move from Matlab to Python numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I am new to python so by gentle with me , I try to convert code from Matlab to numpy python , I am working with matrix .

I have some basic question (that I didn't found the answers in Google):

What is the equivalent for the ' tag for example : H' , H= H*H'

What is the equivalent for the / (mrdivide) tag for example :  H= H/A

Thanks,
MAK

Comment: FYI: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Answer (score 4):

- [`'` (transpose)](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) means the *conjugate* transpose of a matrix. For real matrices, it is given by [`np.transpose(arr)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) or the shorthand [`arr.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html). For complex matrices, you need to use more complicated `arr.conj().T`.
- [`/` (mrdivide)](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html) solves the equation `x A = b` -> `x = b / A` using least squares ([`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)). This is equivalent to `(x A)^T = b^T -> A^T x^T = b^T`, which can be done using `np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, b.T).T`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answers!! . In your answer you make a little work around job :-) , you use the equation B/A = (A'\B')' (np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, b.T).T). Thare any straightforward method in numpy for solves the equation B/A? .  In addition the method (np.linalg.lstsq) work only for A n-by-n matrix and B is a matrix with n columns ? or like matlab give full solution ?, again THANKS!!!!